# Firefox extension: get click data when context menu

Tags: javascript, firefox, contextmenu

In my extension I want to hide/show items on the context menu based on the url I get:

1. from a link if the user opens the context menu over one,
2. from the text selected, also if the user opens the context menu over the text.

In the function to show/hide items in the context menu I do the following check:

```
if (gContextMenu.onLink) {
   url = gContextMenu.target.href;
}     
if (gContextMenu.isTextSelected) {
   url = content.window.getSelection();
}
```

If some text is selected in the page, and the user opens the context menu over a link, both conditions are true. Also, if some text is selected, and the user opens the context menu anywhere in the page (over the selection or not), the `isTextSelected` flag is also true.

Is there a way I can detect what is the real element over which the user has used the right click? How can I know if the right click was over the selected text or not?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is `gContextMenu.target`, which contains the `Node` which was under the cursor, if any (aka. it might be `null` in very rare cases).

The `gContextMenu` code actually [uses `gContextMenu.target` to initialize things like `.onLink`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/992cf3981ca8/browser/base/content/nsContextMenu.js#l707)

As for checking if the the focused node is actually contained within the current selection, you can use [`.getSelection().containsNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection.containsNode) on the focused document.

```
var isFocusedNodeInCurrentSelection = false;
var selection = gContextMenu.focusedWindow &&
  gContextMenu.focusedWindow.getSelection();
if (selection) {
  isFocusedNodeInCurrentSelection =
    selection.containsNode(gContextMenu.target, true);
}
// Do something with that information.
```